# Bootstrap is not supporting on windows xp IE8

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I am using bootstrap in my project . This is working fine in all of the browsers in windows 7 and it's also working fine in Firefox and chrome of windows xp But it's not working in IE8 on windows xp . I have included Respond.js but nothing is working for me .

Here is the code for Respond.js :

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: do you think you can pull up a plunker for us so that we can have a look

Comment: In your current code you only run respond.js when the browser is IE 9 because the if statement

Comment: @Christophvh — **lt** means LESS THAN. 8 is less than 9.

Comment: @Quentin woops, yes my bad. read over it

Comment: [Windows XP should not be allowed on the Internet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windowsforbusiness/end-of-xp-support)

Comment: There are thousands of employee in the company , they are upgrading bit by bit to windows 7 and above , but before the upgradation of all over the company to windows 7 or above platform, we have to make our web application ready for xp users also

Comment: @Quentin the use of respond.js solved my problem for windows 7 users who are using IE8 . but it's not working for windows xp IE8